# How can i run castle activerecord in medium trust hosting?

Tags: castle-activerecord

I have followed the [guidelines](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/pre-generate-lazy-loading-proxies.aspx) to generate the proxy and yet i get the following security exception

```
[SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.]
Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Internal.ActiveRecordModelBuilder..cctor() +0
```

How can i correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a build of ActiveRecord that has the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute defined, see [Run in Medium Trust](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/run-in-medium-trust.aspx)